Abp.io MAUI Android app will not run in Release Mode
I have 2 .NET MAUI apps that are based on Abp.io Commercial version 8.1.4 that I am unable to get to run past the splash screen on the Android when I compile it in Release mode. I have found many issues published in SO and some have answers, but none of them have worked for me. I have enabled DEBUG in Release mode and that oddly enough allows the app to work. Unfortunately you cannot submit an .aab to Google that has debug symbols embedded in it, so that is not an option. There is something about removing the DEBUG symbols from the app that makes it no longer work and I am at my wits end trying to figure it out.
The behavior is very inconsistent. I have created a brand new app using Abp.io commercial and did nothing but change the Url for where it was to get access to the API and compiled it in release mode and was able to get it to actually get past the splash screen. I then used ABP SUITE to add classes and their associated services and recompiled without doing anything else to it and the app immediately hangs on the splash screen.
I installed Sentry in the app and one time captured a Socket exception while in debug mode, but the app does not hang on the splash screen and appears to work as expected; again as long as it is in debug mode.
With Android version 34 the Exported attribute must be explicitly set in the activities. For the MainActivity I have the Exported = true. There is a WebAuthenticatorCallBackActivity that is part of the base framework of Abp.io that I tried setting the Exported to both true and false, but neither setting seems to make a difference in the failure/hanging.
I don't know what else to say about the issue other than to reiterate that it only happens on Android in Release mode without DEBUG symbols. I have been trying to get past this issue for over 3 months with no success. If anyone has a solution (or even a good hint) I would really appreciate it.

the difference between Debug and Release is not only symbolication.  Generally the Linker behavior is different and that is most commonly the source of these types of problems

This is how I have the settings for release:  
false
None
false
.dll;.png;.jpg
None

